# Standalone Executable with Kivy?

Tags: package, kivy, kivy-language

I recently created my first Windows package for a small app I made using Kivy. I have a few questions with regard to running the app.

First, is there a way to get the app to run without a record log popping up in another window? It is just ugly and doesn't seem like something I want in my final "product".

Second, how can I run the app from my desktop? Right now I have a shortcut placed on my desktop, but if I wanted to send my app to a friend, how could I send it to them where they can simply have an icon on their desktop to click on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The entire process is done in 2 steps.

**Step 1:** Make the windows executable files (not Python files)
You'll need to use PyInstaller to create EXE for Windows. Here's the link
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

You will notice a new folder created where all the files are kept along with the application executable file.

**Step 2:** Pack these into a Single Installer File (EXE you are looking for)
You can use a third part software like InstallForge to create a single package installer for these files.

This EXE file can be share with anyone and they can install the program just like any other windows software